# Why are so few things @specialized in Scala's standard library?

Tags: performance, scala, collections, autoboxing, specialized-annotation

I've searched for the use of `@specialized` in the source code of the standard library of Scala 2.8.1. It looks like only a handful of traits and classes use this annotation: `Function0`, `Function1`, `Function2`, `Tuple1`, `Tuple2`, `Product1`, `Product2`, `AbstractFunction0`, `AbstractFunction1`, `AbstractFunction2`.

None of the collection classes are `@specialized`. Why not? Would this generate too many classes?

This means that using collection classes with primitive types is very inefficient, because there will be a lot of unnecessary boxing and unboxing going on.

What's the most efficient way to have an immutable list or sequence (with `IndexedSeq` characteristics) of `Int`s, avoiding boxing and unboxing?

Comment: Wow, cheez, i assumed that `List` and `IndexedSeq` are specialized. Doing some `:javap -c` with the new scala 2.9 REPL shows they still do boxing all the time. The constructors are optimized though it seems (`List(1,2,3)` uses a `wrapIntArray`).

Comment: That's really unwanted overhead when dealing with huge datasets of numbers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Specialization has a high cost on the size of classes, so it must be added with careful consideration. In the particular case of collections, I imagine the impact will be huge.

Still, it is an on-going effort -- Scala library has barely started to be specialized.

Comment: This is correct. Video from Scala Days 2010 on @Specialized, where Iulian Dragos explains why it's not everywhere: http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/151

Comment: I've also grepped through the source of the Scala 2.9 RC1 library and unfortunately it looks like nothing has changed yet!

Comment: @Daniel `Specialization has a high cost on the size of classes, so it must be added with careful consideration` As a naive, non-compiler engineer, why does the size of classes matter? I am **not** making an argument, but looking to learn why.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Well, for one thing, up to Java 7, it was [limited to 64 KB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.1). It can also present problems when coding for Android.

Answer (score 17):

Specialized can be expensive ( **exponential** ) in both size of classes and compile time. Its not just the size like the accepted answer says.

Open your scala REPL and type this.

```
import scala.{specialized => sp}
trait S1[@sp A, @sp B, @sp C, @sp D] { def f(p1:A): Unit }
```

Sorry :-). Its like a compiler bomb.

Now, lets take a simple trait

```
trait Foo[Int]{ }
```

The above will result in two compiled classes. Foo, the pure interface and Foo$1, the class implementation.

Now,

```
trait Foo[@specialized A] { }
```

A specialized template parameter here gets expanded/rewritten for 9 different primitive types ( void, boolean, byte, char, int, long, short, double, float ). So, basically you end up with 20 classes instead of 2.

Going back to the trait with 5 specialized template parameters, the classes get generated for every combination of possible primitive types. i.e its exponential in complexity.

2 * 10 ^  <sup>(no of specialized parameters)</sup>

If you are defining a class for a specific primitive type, you should be more explicit about it such as

```
trait Foo[@specialized(Int) A, @specialized(Int,Double) B] { }
```

Understandably one has to be frugal using specialized when building general purpose libraries.

[Here](http://youtu.be/o2WtIroR7Ag?t=34m17s) is Paul Phillips ranting about it.

Comment: But you don't always need to specialze for all eight primitive types plus `void`; you can also just specialize for `Int`, for example, using `@specialized(Int)`.

Comment: yes, thats right. Added more notes to my answer. But, thats the case when you are doing something specific to a data type. Building general purpose libraries like the the scala language api needs to be more general purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer to my own question: I can wrap an array in an `IndexedSeq` like this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq

def arrayToIndexedSeq[@specialized(Int) T](array: Array[T]): IndexedSeq[T] = new IndexedSeq[T] {
  def apply(idx: Int): T = array(idx)
  def length: Int = array.length
}
```

(Ofcourse you could still modify the contents if you have access to the underlying array, but I would make sure that the array isn't passed to other parts of my program).

Comment: Since you are hiding behind IndexedSeq that still doesn't convince the compiler not to use autoboxing. For instance, if i run the `:javap -c` on the following: `object Test { val a = arrayToIndexedSeq( Array(1,2,3)); val i: Int = a(0)}` -- you will see that val i = a(0) _does_ boxing (in `SeqLike`)....

Comment: @Sciss Ok... grrr! Is there another way to get rid of the unnecessary autoboxing? Is directly using mutable arrays the only way to avoid it?

Comment: I don't know. I guess we need to make a petition to add more specializations to the collections. Martin Odersky kind of promised that here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7285 ; the problem i guess is due to the heavy factoring out of traits in the new collections that if you want Vector to be specialized, you will end up having to specialize a dozen involved traits, which in turn creates high bloat on the size of the library. Still, I think we should vote for that, it definitely sucks to have weak performance for Vector which is really the number crunching swiss army knife in scala.

Comment: @Sciss I've carefully looked at the output of `scalac -print ...` and following the sequence of methods being called, it looks like it actually does avoid boxing when I call `apply()` on it. (Using scala 2.8.1). There are some calls to `scala.Int.box()` but those are not called for that code path.

Comment: Your collection however does have one advantage: it does not box stored elements, and that's a huge memory saving if the collection is (moderately) large. An integer is 4 bytes, boxing will probably add at least other 16 bytes to that (for object headers and the pointers to objects). When you extract one int, only that is boxed.