# Why do Scala for loops with a yield autobox ints when converting to a collection?

Tags: scala, for-loop, autoboxing

When using `range` in Scala 2.12 and proceeding to iterate over the elements why do ints get boxed into `java.lang.Integer` when they are yielded? The below code allocates 10,000 Integers on the heap.

```
val boxedSeq = for (i <- 1 to 10000) yield i
println("Done")
```

If instead of yielding you print it, no Integers are created. Is the root cause that generic sequences cannot contain primitives [1](https://scalac.io/specialized-generics-object-instantiation/)?

```
for (i <- 1 to 10000) println(i)
println("Done")
```

[10k Integers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ltdn.png)

[Integers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFVOg.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are so few things @specialized in Scala's standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477675/why-are-so-few-things-specialized-in-scalas-standard-library)

Answer (score 0):

You can check:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

When you are using yield with for in Scala it is translated to

```
.map((i) => {...})
```

It means that you are creating List and it has to contains objects.

When you are not using yield it is:

```
.foreach(i) {...}
```

And there you do not need any object.